# Can I use a string in a JSON file to access a Swift view from within another view?

Tags: json, swift, string, xcode

I want to setup a single master detail view that I would like to populate with data from a JSON file, but in each detail view (100+ of them) there needs to be text that is formatted with bold, bold and underlined, etc. I don’t think I can include the formatted text in the JSON file, so I have created separate views for each instance of custom text that I would like the master detail view to access from a callout in a JSON file. Is that possible? I hope that makes sense. (I'm hoping to avoid creating a ton of individual detail views.) I'm working in Xcode v 14.01, Swift v 5.7.

Here’s what I have…

"SampleDescription()" is the first view that contains the custom formatted text that I'm hoping that to access using a JSON string.

FWIW, here is a sample of the formatted text from view file "SampleDescription()"...

```
        Text("**This Text Is Bold –** This text is regular. \(Text("**This text is bold and underlined**").underline()) \(Text("this text is regular.")) \(Text("**This text is bold and underlined**").underline()) \(Text("this text is regular.")) \(Text("**This text is bold and underlined**").underline()) \(Text("this text is regular _this text is italic._"))")
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .lineSpacing(5)
}
```

Here's the first entry in my JSON file...

```
{
    "name": "TITLE",
    "id": 1001,
    "imageName": "1_nonum",
    "description": "SampleDescription()",
    "level": "Level",
    "usedin": "Used In",
    "url": "URL"
}
```

In the JSON file "SampleDescription()" is the view that I want to access. Should it include the () or not? Should it be bracketed or something else, is this doable? I have tried with and without () both as a String and as Data. It seems like there's a simple solution that I'm just not seeing.

Here is my Detail file (Sign.swift):

```
struct Sign: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var level: String
    var usedin: String
    var url: URL


private var imageName: String
    var image: Image {
      Image(imageName)
}
```

Should "var description: String" be String, or Data, or something else? Should it be separated out from this?

Here is my ModelData file:

```
var signs: [Sign] = load("signsData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
let data: Data

guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
}

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
}
```

Here is the DetailView file where I would like to access the “SampleDescription() view from the JSON file:

struct SignDetail: View {
var sign: Sign

```
var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        
        Text(sign.name) //THIS ACCESSES JSON DATA AS WANTED
            .padding(.all)
        
        SampleDescription() //THIS IS THE VIEW THAT I WANT TO ACCESS BUT AS A VARIABLE FROM A JSON FILE
        
        
//      sign.description //SOMETHING LIKE THIS IS HOW I WANT TO ACCESS THE VIEW FROM THE JSON FILE
            
    }
}
```

Everything other than "description" is being accessed from my JSON files exactly as desired.

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: You can say Ttxt that you are passing an string with attributes to convert to AttributedString : Text(.init(sign.description))

Comment: You can store formatted text in JSON, use base64 encode/decode. Then you won't need many views. But you can also just name all your views and use the name field in the json to select the view you want to load.